# How to Protect Base Field's Public/Private

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

If i have a **ClassA**

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        public string name;
    }
```

Where Attribute Name is Public ,and it can be modified from Anywhere .
Than i have a **ClassB**

```
    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        private string name;//But it's not Woking ,name is still public
    }
```

...which Inherit's ClassA ,but i need at ClassB to make `name` as Private Field.
So if i create an Object of Type **ClassB** than `ClassB.name` cannot be modified .

Comment: are you sure you want to have two fields with same name? Wouldn't already help to declare name protected in ClassA so only ClassA and ClassB can access to it?

Comment: @Davide Piras yes im sure ,because the ClassA.name should be Visible and not Validated but at ClassB.name is my Concern i should make it Private .

Comment: don't make fields public - bad design

Comment: If you don't want `ClassB.name` to be modified make it `readonly` (you need to use properties instead of fields)

Comment: @Carsten not all public fields are bad design. public readonly fields are IMHO best suited for immutable DTOs.

Comment: @Mikael: ok in that special case ... but why make a DTO immutable, give it a constructor or make it a class ... ;)

Comment: @Carsten It's going to need a ctor of course, because of the readonly thing. And it's always a class, since the size most of the times are larger than a struct could handle. But the main thing is that I just like to have them as public readonly fields since that makes it impossible to add any kind of logic behind the getters.

Comment: @Mikael - sorry I should try not to be clever with the ";)" thingg - of course you need the ctor to be immutable but my point is this: A DTO is just a simple class/struct without behaviour and you could view a constructor if it's the only way to set the data. I think we both mean the same thing but I prefere "public int IntValue {get;set}" and you like "public int IntValue;"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just don't publish the field but accessors:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } protected set { _name = value; } }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
  /* nothing left to do - you can set Name in here but not from outside */
}
```

Comment: But in ClassA Name is not really "public" - you can't change value of it outside ClassA and ClassB :((

Comment: @Prator12 and nor should you. If you make Name changeable in class A you can allways do something like `((ClassA)objectB).Name = "and it is setable";`

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can not change visibility of base class's field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot change A, do not use inheritance, but aggregation and delegation:

```
public class A {
  public string name;
  public int f() { return 42; }
}

public class B {
  private A a;
  public int f() { return a.f(); }
  public string getName() { return a.name; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Carsten Konig's method is a good way, and here is an alternative.

```
public class ClassA {
    public virtual string Name {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA {
    public override string Name {
        get {
            return base.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm. There is a pair of tricks for this. But none of them is what you really want. One is:

```
    public class ClassA 
    {
        protected string name;
        public string Name { get { return name; } public set { name = value; } }
    }

public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
         public new string Name { get { return base.name; } }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have control over ClassA, you can do this:

```
void Main()
{   
    var b = new ClassB();
    var a = (ClassA)b;
    a.name = "hello";
    b.PrintName();
}

class ClassA {
    public string name;
}

class ClassB : ClassA  {
    private new string name;
    public void PrintName() {
        Console.WriteLine(base.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's not just a Printing Issue

Comment: It's the `new` keyword that is the solution here. That hides the previously public field.